# How I do circular shifting (rotation) of int in Python?

Tags: python, rotation, bit-shift, bitmask

In Java right rotation is done using:

```
 (bits >>> k) | (bits << (Integer.SIZE - k))
```

But how to do similar thing in Python?

I tried to do (as described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rotate-bits-of-an-integer/)):

```
n = 13
d = 2
INT_BITS = 4
print(bin(n))
print(bin((n >> d)|(n << (INT_BITS - d)) & 0xFFFFFFFF))
```

Output:

```
0b1101
0b110111
```

But I could not interpret this as a right rotation.

Also is it possible to perform the rotation by excluding leading zeroes, for example:

rightRotation of (`...0001101`) = `1110` not  `1000...110`

Comment: Revisit the site, you miss the `& 0xFFFFFFFF` part for the right rotation.

Comment: Thank you, @SimonFink I edited my question, but still produce wrong output.

Comment: It is a mistake, it should be '0xF' for a four number of bit, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is my mistake, if you want to change `INT_BITS` to 4 you also need to change `0xFFFFFFFF` to `0xF` (one hex equals 4-bits):

```
n = 13
d = 2
INT_BITS = 4
print(bin(n))
print(bin((n >> d)|(n << (INT_BITS - d)) & 0xF))
```

will output:

```
0b1101
0b111
```